# how to create two fillable array in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, model

laravel two $fillable array for addition(create) and modification(update)
$fillable1 for create 
and
$fillable2 for update
for example

```
//in model
protected $fillable1 = [
'id', 'email','name', 'phone',
];//for create

protected $fillable2 = [
'name', 'phone'
];//for update

//in controler
public function store
User::create($request->all());

public function update
User::findOrFail($user_id)->fill($request->all())->save();
```

so in this example column email will be creatable but not editable

```
User::create($request->all());
User::create($request->$fillable1());
```

and

```
User::findOrFail($user_id)->fill($request->all())->save();
User::findOrFail($user_id)->fill($request->$fillable2())->save();
```

Comment: just validate your request to have the included `$fillable` you want! I mean make 2 `FormRequest`s, 1 for Create and 1 for Update, and call `$request->validated()` to fill the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$fillable` used by Model,  So, you will need one variable **$fillable**.

Try to use this:

```
protected $hidden = [
   'email', 'password',
];
```

or **Just modify your Controller** to update only what you want :)

```
User::findOrFail($user_id)->fill(['values_here'])->save();
```

Comment: if I put email in fillable and hidden the email is editable and creatable

and if I put it only in hidden its not creatable

Comment: Hiding Attributes From JSON is not useful for our situation

Comment: I think you can use the same protected `$fillable = ['email','name', 'phone',]; ` (I removed id, normally it's assigned by database) because it only fills the fields in the params. I mean if you use`->fill(['name'=>'xyz'])` you only fill the name. And have in mind the `$guard` attr to protect your not fillable data by default